# passing List<MyModel> from my controller in the "WebInterfaceProject" to the processor method in "DataLibraryProject"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the following error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 22: cannot convert from `'System.Collections.Generic.List<WebInterfaceProject.Models.MyModel>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.List<DataLibraryProject.Models.MyModel>'`

Here is where I'm passing List from my controller in the "WebInterfaceProject" to the processor method in "DataLibraryProject"...

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Form_Submit(MyModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        int id = EditFormDetails_SP(
            ...
            , model.MyListObject // here is where i get the Error 
            ...
        ); 

    }
    return RedirectToAction("MyView", "Explore", new { i = id });
}
```

this is the processor method in "DataLibraryProject"

```
public static int EditFormDetails_SP( List<MyModel> model )
{
    //i want to do stuff with the [List<MyModel> model]...


    return ...
}
```

class in "WebInterfaceProject"

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<MyModel> MyListObject { get; set; }
}
```

class in "DataLibraryProject"

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<MyModel> MyListObject { get; set; }
}
```

I know i'm probably making a stupid rookie mistake here, but I am having a hard time finding the vocabulary to describe this problem so my google searches have not been fruitful. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can't really help here with the information in your question except to say it seems the `EditFormDetails_SP` method is expecting you to pass a `List<DataLibraryProject.Models.MyModel>` but your `model.MyListObject` is a `List<WebInterfaceProject.Models.MyModel>` - why have you got two models? If you must have two models, then you might need to convert them from one type to the other, say using something like [AutoMapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Getting-started.html)?

Comment: you're right, that is why it's throwing the error. what is confusing to me is that this kind of passing has worked when i am passing primitive types, but seems to not accept more complex objects like List<T> types. To give some more background info, the models in the `WebInterfaceProject` generally have additional objects that are only being used within the web interface layer, and the `DataLibraryProject` models are usually pared-down versions of the same models that contain objects being used for submission to the DB .

Comment: Yes that is correct, generics using primitive types, like List<string>, can be defined anywhere and they can be used interchangeably, but any custom type that happens to have the same class name and signature cannot. 
 (i.e. WebInterfaceProject.Models.MyModel is a different type than DataLibraryProject.Models.MyModel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define "MyModel" in one location only.  I'd suggest:

1. Delete "MyModel" from the WebInterfaceProject
2. Add DataLibraryProject as a reference to the WebInterfaceProject.  To do that, right-click the WebInterfaceProject in Visual Studio -> Add -> Reference -> select the DataLibraryProject
3. Add "using DataLibraryProject;" to the top of your controller
4. Build

Comment: upvoted. i'll wait for more suggestions before investigating/accepting.